# Why is Black Hole Information paradox so important to physicists?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, black-holes, quantum-information, quantum-gravity

It's a very general question. Black hole paradox is an interesting problem but why is it something that physicists are so worried about? As neither can it be directly experimentally tested nor do I see any indirect proof of it, then what relevance does it have?

I might have upset some of folks here, but I've got no hard feelings here. But as far as I've seen, people doing Quantum Gravity or related fields, always have their eyes on this paradox. I'm just curious to know why is it so important?

Comment: Because it seems like an obstacle when you want to reconcile gravity with quantum theory?

Comment: "Sacred" is not a good word to use here.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Is it the only obstacle? Because there are a lot of other problems with Gravity and Quantum Mechanics, which seem to get lost among major physics community.

Comment: @Dev I'm not sure where you're getting that information that other problems get lost among physicists, it's very common in particle physics communities to reference issues where analysis breaks down because we don't have a theory of quantum gravity other than that which comes from black holes (black holes are typically far from particle physicists minds).

Comment: This video from PBS Space Time may help - [The Black Hole Information Paradox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9XkHBmE-N34)

Answer (score 7):

Black holes have been advertised to be laboratories for quantum gravity in the theoretical sense. The previous century has been a witness to the power of a thought experiment.

The black hole information problem lies at the heart of quantum gravity, in that an innocuous quantum analysis applied to black holes, namely Hawking radiation, leads to an apparent violation of a core tenet of quantum theory, which is unitarity. Since we do not have a full quantum theory of gravity, we do not know which structures of either gravity or quantum theory will remain. Resolving such a tension caused by black hole evaporation will give us hints as to those structures that remain, are lost, or are replaced by something more fundamental.